# enforce the output value of MLP network to be zero if they are naturally small

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, deep-learning

I build a MLP type of network to perform regression type of analysis. The prediction plot is given as follows. It can be observed that there exist a lot of noisy spikes (or spikes with small values). Is that possible to enforce the learned network to reduce the number of those noisy(small) spikes, i.e., the output value of the corresponding points tend to be zero.

[image]

The model architecture along with the size of training data are shown as following

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that temporal data you are trying to predict? If it is temporal, then the network you are using is a convolutional neural network which is used on spatial data like images.A simple MLP won't need to use convolutional layers and max pooling. Practically, it is not possible to enforce the learned or trained network to reduce the number of spikes. You might try to retrain it and change the hyperparameters. But I would recommend trying to look at Echo State Networks for prediction on temporal data. It is a reservoir based network and works fairly well on temporal data.